# Are Laravel automatic injection for only controller functions?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Here is an issue, when I call controller function using request through router, Laravel does automatic injection. For example:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    // do staff
}
```

here `Request`  is passed automatically, but if I call this `store()` function form same controller's other function, it says that I need to pass 1 argument. It doesn't injects `Request` automatically, so why is that? Laravel injects variable automatically only for functions on router? how?

Comment: If you call the `store` method explicitly you'll need to satisfy the arguments. Laravel does this behind the scenes when you make an http request.

Comment: can you tell me where I can find this logic inside laravel code? inside RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: You can use controller functions without `Request $request`. But when you comes to middle-ware, You should pass the request

Comment: Can you add your routes/web.php file? I guess the route has a placeholder, and it will go first before the auto-injected stuff.

Comment: in an MVC framework, calling a controller action from another place of code is not a good practice. Controller actions should only be used for mapping certain type of requests to them and take control. If you want to perform the same operation - in this case // do stuff - in different places of your app, put that logic into an encapsulated service/helper class. Then inject this class into your controller action or instantiate it manually wherever you need it and call the function that performs the operation.

Comment: I know that it's not a good practice, I am just interested how this is implemented inside laravel code

Answer (score 3):

Laravel's auto dependency injection only works if the objects are instantiated from the IOC container. When a route is resolved to a Controller action, Laravel does it through the container. So if there are any dependencies in the Controller method they are resolved automatically. But if you call the method directly like `$object->method()`, the dependencies are not resolved automatically.

So in your case you cannot do `$this->store()`. But you can do like this -->

```
$container = \Illuminate\Container\Container::getInstance();
$container->call([$this, 'store'], []); //$container->call([$object, 'method'], [args]);
```

This is also true for other custom classes. If these classes are resolved through the Laravel's container, their constructor dependencies are resolved automatically.

Ex:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $dependency;

    public function __construct(AnotherClass $dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the instance of the `MyClass` object through the container like this-->

```
$instance = $container->make(MyClass::class);
```

The container will automatically instantiate `AnotherClass`. This is equal to:

```
$instance = new MyClass(new AnotherClass());
```

If `AnotherClass` has dependencies, the container will recursively instantiate them.

Example is taken from: [source](https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/bd857d9b0ac895df7604dd2e63b23afe)

Answer (score 0):

You could try resolving from the service container "manually" when you call the controller method:

```
$this->store(app('Request'));
```

But it seems like you might want a different pattern here than this.